# How to let the portrait app in landscape mode

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I customize the android system, the resolution is `1024x768` The target device must be in the landscape mode, it's fixed. And some apps are only have the portrait mode, can not be used.

So I want to change something that let the portrait app display in the center and the resolution is `640x480` How can I do it? I can do anything, including change the android or linux kernel code.

[image: like this]

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do it?

For apps that you write yourself, you modify the apps to run successfully in landscape mode.

For apps that your firm intends to license from other developers, have them make a landscape-compatible version of the app as a precondition of your license.

If you intend to allow third-party apps to be installed on this device by the end user, modify the installation process to detect the fact that one or more activities are flagged as running landscape-only and present a warning to the user at install time, so they know that the app they are trying to install will not run well on your device.

Modifying Android in the manner you describe may be possible, but it is the sort of thing that will require lots of time and effort and is well outside the scope of a StackOverflow question.